# Remove inner style from HTML using Regex C#

Tags: c#, css, regex

I want to remove inner style from html by using c#. Here is my Html text

```
    <span style="font-family: tahoma; color: #9bbb59;">This is a simple text.</span><br />
<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;R1C1</td>
            <td>R1C2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>R2C1</td>
            <td>R2C2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<style type="text/css" id="telerik-reTable-1">
    .telerik-reTable-1   {
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    }
    .telerik-reTable-1 td.telerik-reTableFooterEvenCol-1  {
    padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: solid gray 1.0pt;
    }
</style>
```

I want it to looks like after remove inner css.

```
 <span style="font-family: tahoma; color: #9bbb59;">This is a simple text.</span><br />
<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;R1C1</td>
            <td>R1C2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>R2C1</td>
            <td>R2C2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I used this pattern `@"<\s*style[^(style>)]*style>"`. But it's not working.

> Note: I think I cann't use HtmlDocument to remove child node. Because
>   it does not maintain parent child node relationship. so I want to use
>   regular expression to remove the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern to match.

```
<style[^<]*</style\s*>
```

Explanation:

- `<style`  match `<` and `style` word.
- `[^<]*`   match any character which is not `<` and this match occur
  multiple time till `<` occur.
- `</`      match exactly `</`.
- `style\s*>` match `style` word, zero or more space character after it and
  `>`.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use regex to parse HTML documents. Check this question to understand why.

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

You should do it with HTML Parser, like [**Html Agility Pack**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/). Here how you can do it.

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlInput);

        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//style");

        foreach (var node in nodes)
            node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

        string htmlOutput = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Comment: @corei11 find the span element which style is equal to this, set the style attribute to ""

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform with an style sheet like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="style" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```